# Aws EC2 : Can we use aws certificate for generateServiceProviderMetadata method saml

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, saml, onelogin

i am using saml method generateServiceProviderMetadata because my IDP need metadata and entityId for my application . generateServiceProviderMetadata method need 2 parameters (decryptionCert, signingCert) for this we have to pass decryptionPvk(decryption_key) privateCert(signing_key) to saml strategy .

for genrating pem i used command
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout signing_key.pem -out signing_cert.pem -nodes -days 900

$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout decryption_key.pem -out decryption_cert.pem -nodes -days 900

but open ssl is self signed certificate(self signed will not work), On aws ec2 domain can i use aws certificate so i can genrate meta data

Can Anyone Help Me Out

i need metadata and entityId for my saml application so i can give that to IDP